# Peroxisomes catalase

Tags: cells, hydrogen-peroxide

I know peroxisome has many functions like detoxification, oxidation of certain fatty acids which leads to production of hydrogen peroxide,I wanna know how does hydrogen peroxide in cytosol gets in to peroxisome. It has catalase. Is peroxisome the only site where hydrogen peroxide gets metabolised? Even from mitochondria there is h2O2 release? My main question is: does peroxisome destroy h2O2 produced by itself only or even the H2O2 present in cytosol?

Comment: What makes you think that hydrogen peroxide enters the peroxisome from the cytosol? It would be helpful if you provide references/citations to what you've read to help identify what you're understanding and where exactly you're stuck. If you don't have a specific medical tie-in to your question, it may also have a better home on our site for Biology; I can move it there, if you'd like, once you've added some background.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I was just thinking how does peroxisome detoxify h2O2 in the cytosol? Is there h202 in cytosol?

Comment: Okay, it would be helpful if you provide references/citations to what you've already read so we can understand the background of your question and your existing understanding.